# Mockito mocking - Why do I need to provide dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I want to mock a service for a spring unit test, I thought if using mockito to mock a dependency then I would not have to then mock all the dependencies that Mock had and so on.

An example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ValidatorTestConfiguration.class)
public class ValidatorTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
@Configuration
protected static class ValidatorTestConfiguration
{       
    @Bean
    public ITestValidator getTestValidator()
    {
        return new TestValidator();
    }


    @Bean
    public CheckSumValidator getCheckSumValidator()
    {
        return new CheckSumValidator();
    }


    @Bean
    public ITestService getTestService()
    {
        return Mockito.mock(TestService.class);
    }
}

@Autowired
private ITestService TestService;


@Autowired
private ITestValidator TestValidator;


@BeforeClass
public void setUp()
{
    //Here I want to use Mockito to override methods being called in the service
}


@Test
public void testHasValidFormat()
{
    final boolean hasValidIdFormat = this.testValidator.hasValidFormat("123456");
    assertEquals(true, hasValidIdFormat);
}
}
```

I thought that by mocking the TestService that I would not need to worry about all the dependencies that it needs?

The problem I am getting is that spring is complaining that the depdencies required by the service that is injected into the validator are not available to be autowired.

I would normally just use mockito annotations to do this but the 3rd party checksum class I am using is final so Mockito cannot mock this and I want to call the real methods in this class whilst stubbing the response of the service method calls.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. What is the exact issue you're seeing?

Comment: just loads of "No qualifying bean of type ..." for the dependencies the service has.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Something is missing from your question. Provide an MCVE.

Comment: Well I can flesh out the example if that would help.

Comment: You should be using `Mockito.mock(ITestService.class)`. It should be the interface, not the concrete class, unless you have any special requirements.

Comment: hmmm... @metacubed Can you make that the answser?!? That works, I cant believe it.. I feel pretty stupid! I have to admit I havent done it this way before but I was unable to use the annotation way because one of the classes is final and Mockito would not mock it,

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestValidatorTestConfiguration.class)` isn't using the configuration that you have defined in your class. `ValidatorTestConfiguration`

Comment: Good spot, actually none of those class names are real. I have changed it but that isnt the reason this was happening.

Comment: Sure, @berimbolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "program to an interface" and have a handy interface that you use, it is recommended to create mocks using that interface instead of the concrete class. That way, you bypass any logic inside the implementation.

```
@Bean
public ITestService getTestService()
{
    return Mockito.mock(ITestService.class);
}
```

When you create a Mockito mock for a class, it tries to execute the constructor/init logic inside that class as part of its mocking. So when you mock the concrete class `TestService`, you are invoking some of its logic. Since it has dependencies which are not mocked, you get the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was a mistake on my part and looking at other code samples from the project the interface is usually used when using the normal initMocks method.

Comment: No, Mockito does not execute the `TestService` constructor when you do `Mockito.mock(TestService.class)` (it uses Objenesis to avoid that). So, the real explanation for the Spring failures is something else.

Comment: @Rogério, Spring does execute static constructors, class init blocks and field autowiring. I can edit my answer to make that distinction clear.

Comment: Well, I said that *Mockito* does not execute the constructor when `Mockito.mock(X.class)` is called, and that is true. Spring, of course, does execute constructors (and static initializers, which Mockito also does execute).